# What is the probability that an expanding bipartite graph exists with the property, |V1|=|V2|?

Tags: probabilistic-algorithms

I want to find a bound on the above problem, and show that a random graph has a positive probability of being an expanding bipartite with the property, |V1|=|V2|. I am not getting, where should I start.

Apologies for not writing my understanding, I am very much stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by positive probability? probability cant be nagative...except in quantum mechanics (complex amplitudes). Anyway, i suggest you take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051954/probability-that-a-graph-is-bipartite

Comment: Apologies, I didn't make myself clear. Here positive is non zero, which means there is a chance of having the above event occur.

Comment: @ManikaSharma Am I correct in assuming your problem is the following: you want to prove the existence of a bipartite expander for which $|V_1|=|V_2|$, and you want to do this by using a (non-constructive) probabilistic argument? I.e. you want to take a random bipartite graph and show that the probability it is an expander is non-zero/positive (which proves there exists such a graph). The problem is your question is ill-defined as the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ is an expander.

Comment: If you ask that the graph be $d$-regular for some constant $d$, then the question becomes more interesting (see for instance https://theory.epfl.ch/courses/topicstcs/Lecture3.pdf, http://www.tcs.tifr.res.in/~prahladh/teaching/05spring/lectures/lec2.pdf)

If this is indeed what you want I can write an actual answer, but you first need to clarify a bit.